# Resize Slider Image in ICarousel

Tags: ios, objective-c, icarousel

I am using icarousel image slider. My image width is more then 1300px then how can I fit it into single screen currently it's overlap on next image index.

Answer (score 0):

Using `carouselItemWidth` delegate may help,

Use:

```
- (CGFloat)carouselItemWidth:(iCarousel *)carousel;
```

Like,

```
- (CGFloat)carouselItemWidth:(iCarousel *)carousel{

    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation))
    {
        //Handle and return as per your image
        return 200; //return value that is equal or higher than your CarouselItemView width
    }
    else
    {
        //Handle and return as per your image
        return 300; //return value that is equal or higher than your CarouselItemView width
    }
}
```

Also you can use below property to get the currently centered item view in the carousel. The index of this view matches currentItemIndex.

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UIView *currentItemView;
```

Comment: Thanks it's working but i had used clip to bounds and it's worked.